Wall studs warping slightly
In 2019, I purchased a Derksen shed and had it placed on my family's property in Texas. Since then I have been finishing out the inside for use as a simple vacation cabin. The shed is 12'x24' and has been up until now very reliable. It should be mentioned that I am not any sort of a tradesman and have been bumbling along with the electrical, plumbing and carpentry work. Sorry if any of the pictures qualify as "DIY gore" or if my questions are just plain stupid.
Earlier this year, I noticed some bowing happening to some of the studs on the west wall. The bowing on this wall seems to be about 1/4" and happening towards the middle of the stud. Looking at the inside of this wall, I don't notice any water damage.
Notice the area to the left of the window and just underneath the rain catchment T.


There is some bowing on the east and north walls mostly towards the bottom of the studs. There is one location where it is bowing in the middle on the north. On the west and north walls, the bowing became severe enough that the panels of the siding started to separate. I used a little clear silicone to fill the gaps. I believe the siding is LP Smartsiding (feel free to fact-check me; maybe I'm wrong).
Here's a picture of the north wall as well as a hole I drilled in the south wall for something unrelated. The purpose of the hole picture is to show the experts (you) what things look like under the siding. Maybe that's just siding, maybe it's thin OSB. I don't know. This hole is under the porch and usually carries a pipe that has the edges crudely sealed with silicone, so I don't think it has any relation to the warping.


The north, west, and east sides of the cabin do not have a porch above them. The south side does, however. Although the south side does show slight bowing towards the bottom of the studs, it's noticeably less than the other three sides, leading me to believe it is either exposure to moisture or heat that is causing the warping. My dad thought that moisture my be getting absorbed by the bottom edge of the siding instead of dripping down. This sounds plausible to me.
I have not noticed any cracking happening to the drywall inside. There is a rain catchment system on the west side which I (stupidly) mounted to the exterior wall. This past summer, a pipe came loose at the T junction and dumped water all down the wall. The past two or three summers have also been excessively hot. I should mention that the north side is not perfectly north, and that it does catch a great deal of direct sunlight in the afternoon.
My questions are these:

Is this something to be concerned about, or is this just par for the course?
What could this be caused by?
What can I do, if anything, to stop or slow the warping?

I was thinking of building a small wraparound porch around the other three sides just to keep the rain off, possibly installing some sun shades, and moving the water catchment system off of the structure entirely.
Thank you very much for any help you can give.

I forgot to mention that when I am at the cabin, I usually have the AC set to 70* F and when I am not present, have it set to about 85* F.

Put all information in your post, please, not in comments.

TL-DR, however The bottom line is that studs are very rarely, perfectly straight, flat and without twist. Since they are sensitive to temperature and humidity, it is not uncommon for them to bow, warp or twist when in use. Particularly when they are sheathed only on one side.
What you are seeing can probably be classified as an inconvenience rather than an issue. Any of your planned projects, ( Porch, sunshades, water dispersement farther away) will all help reduce the possibility of more movement in the studs , but are not a guarantee.
The bottom line is, what you are seeing is normal. You haven't done anything that ruined the structure.

He may get plans for new things and need to scootch everything by 1/32".

@RMDman yes, I think his point is that the tolerance of studs being straight is way bigger than 1/32".
